# Internal Webcam (Macbook Pro 2017) not detected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, webcam, macbook, camera

So I decided to start using Ubuntu (Version 20.04) on my Macbook Pro one day, all was well until I tried to take a picture from my internal camera through Cheese.

The Cheese window is just a blank screen that says: 'No device found' And on any other video recording device that should have access to the camera shows a blank screen with no Input Capture from the camera.

I tried installing the Facetime HD camera drivers for running Ubuntu on a Macbook, but I ran into some errors and in the end, it didn't work.

The websites I tried following the directions are:

https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/wiki/Get-Started#firmware-extraction
https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/wiki/Installation#get-started-on-ubuntu
https://gist.github.com/johnjeffers/3006011ec7767a4101cdd118e8d64290
https://victorleungtw.medium.com/install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-on-macbookpro14-1-9f1b6afde43d

The Ubuntu uname -r outputs:

`5.11.0-40-generic`

None of the solutions on the GitHub websites work as I read every comment.

The only thing I think might be helpful from lspci is:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] (rev c0)`

Output of `sudo lshw -c multimedia` is (Shows no video device, if it helps)

```
*-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:80 memory:82660000-82663fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:79 memory:82720000-82723fff memory:4000000000-400000ffff
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo lshw -c multimedia` in a terminal and add the result to the bottom of your question please.

Comment: This worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/1432776/925128 Cheese didn't work but Kamoso did.  I have also installed the AppleUSBVideoSupport driver.