# What does this command do (echo deep | sudo tee -a /sys/power/mem_sleep)?

Tags: command-line, suspend, 22.04, power-management

I have solved the problem of my laptop waking in 20 seconds like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434727/925128) - see links there. I would like to understand how this works.

That solution is to somehow modify a variable in `/sys/power/mem_sleep`, namely `s2idle` to `deep`.

Looking at that file it contained this single line:

```
s2idle [deep]
```

which was already confusing , given both variables seemed mentioned there, one in brackets.

I didn't need to decide anything though, because, as instructed in the second comment, I haven't tried to change that file as such, but I have used the command:

```
echo deep | sudo tee -a /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

Looking again at that file it seemed **unchanged** though.

After restart the waking from suspend is instantaneous, but that file has the same single line `s2idle [deep]` that it had in the first place.

I have trusted that solution but:

- I don't know how to reverse that in case I had to
- The file seems unchanged so what changing/reversing could mean?

---

Maybe interesting to notice, there is a file at that location `sys/power/wakeup_count` which contains this single line: `20`. Could those be the 20 seconds that I had experienced before?

Comment: This command wrote `deep` to the file. But it had already `deep` selected. It is a default value. The value in brackets shows the value selected. You can try to write `s2idle` and see what happens.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Could it be that in a buggy way that option was not "read" and became active after my command?

Comment: Well, it could be the case...

Comment: @user68186 - Indeed that file and all the others at the same location/folder are marked as recently modified. But the file looks like it was before my command although the suspend/wake behavior is different.

Comment: @Pilot6 - `This command wrote deep to the file`. - `try to write s2idle and see what happens`. You mean to run `echo s2idle | sudo tee -a /sys/power/mem_sleep`? And  should that trigger the line `[s2sleep] deep`?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: HOW TO CHANGE!? IS EDITING THE FILE ALLOWED? It appears not.

Comment: @mathtick - All that remain obscure, the document cannot be manually changed, but it can be changed by that command as seen in my linked answer (see first line of the question) . By the way: don't use uppercase letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote `deep` to that system file. That file has fixed values that you can see. The one in brackets is the selected value. So it doesn't look like you changed anything.

The meaning of the values is:

> The /sys/power/mem_sleep file controls the operating mode of      system
> suspend.  Reading from it returns the available modes         as "s2idle"
> (always present), "shallow" and "deep" (present if        supported).  The
> mode that will be used on subsequent attempts         to suspend the system
> (by writing "mem" to the /sys/power/state         file described above) is
> enclosed in square brackets.
>
> ```
>   Writing one of the above strings to this file causes the mode
>   represented by it to be used on subsequent attempts to suspend the system.
> ```

> ```
>   See Documentation/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.rst for more
>   information.
> ```
>
> The /sys/power/wakeup_count file allows user space to put the         system
> into a sleep state while taking into account the      concurrent arrival
> of wakeup events.  Reading from it returns        the current number of
> registered wakeup events and it blocks if         some wakeup events are
> being processed at the time the file is       read from.  Writing to it
> will only succeed if the current      number of wakeup events is equal to
> the written value and, if         successful, will make the kernel abort a
> subsequent transition         to a sleep state if any wakeup events are
> reported after the        write has returned.

Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-power

Comment: (you seem to have posted twice). Do you know what each variable means? `"s2idle" (always present), "shallow" and "deep" (present if supported)` - I might test them but maybe that is risky?

Comment: Oops. I'll fix it. The second part is about wakeup_count.

Comment: After doing the `s2idle` selection the file was changed as expected (brackets moved onto that). But that didn't change the behavior of my laptop regarding wakeup time. It's still instant. So the problem was different in the first place. Now I don't know what option is better. In the initial comment that provided the solution it says `deep` maybe helpful for power consumption etc. But the initial problem seems buggy, fixed now, but which I cannot track anymore.

Comment: `The second part is about wakeup_count` - my secondary question was in fact "what *is* wakeup count?" And by the way what is the difference between `deep` and `s2idle` - and `shallow`?

Comment: `deep` is default if present. Explanation of `wakeup_count` has been added.

Comment: This looks like a bug (after some update, the initial problem re-appeared and was fixed in the same way: the file `/sys/power/mem_sleep` was already in the form that the command is supposed to trigger, but the latter is needed nonetheless. - Do you have an idea against what package this could be reported (or checked if already reported) as a bug?

Comment: It can be reported against kernel. `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: In fact it seems that after a while in 22.04 and always in 22.10 the opposite command `echo s2idle | sudo tee -a /sys/power/mem_sleep` is the one that is needed! - Very odd and very hard to track. Updated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434727/925128).

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/719830/341192) question contains the pertinent info I was trying to get about what those commands do: `deep` *was* supposed to trigger a longer wake-up time in the first place and lower battery use, `s2idle` is supposed to give short wake-up time and use more energy. Something was wrong in 22.04 and then was fixed. At some point a new problem appeared where `s2idle` was not remembered across reboots (I have to run that command at startup now.)