# Remember /sys/power/mem_sleep setting after reboot

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management, 23.04

I had this solution for the question [Macbook takes 20 seconds to wake up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434722/macbook-takes-20-seconds-to-wake-up) where I had to run `echo s2idle | sudo tee -a /sys/power/mem_sleep` in order to set `/sys/power/mem_sleep` to `[s2idle] deep`
But after some update that change is not remembered after reboot, and that setting is reverted to `s2idle [deep]`.

How can that be fixed so that the needed setting is remembered?

(Or even better - maybe someone has a better solution to the initial problem linked above.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of [running a script after reboot as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/290102/925128).

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Selecting `nano`, added a record to the bottom, containing the path to my script (mentioned in answer under link in question):

```
@reboot path/to/script/to/be/run/as/root
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo s2idle | sudo tee -a /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

We can see user's and root's crontab entries as follows:

```
crontab -l       # list your user crontab entries
sudo crontab -l  # list root's crontab entries
```