# MacBook Air 2017 Build-In Webcam not recognized on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: webcam, macbook

I know that there is a thread which almost sounds the same ([Webcam not working in Ubuntu 22.04 on MacBook Air](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430547/webcam-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-on-macbook-air)), but I followed the instructions in the most upvoted comment, which didn´t work out. I'm completely new to Linux so I'm pretty confused.

Is there any other way to get the camera recognized?

Thanks in advance! =)

EDIT: I didn't get any error at all doing this. It just didn't change anything... I tested it on Cheese and on Google Meet in my Firefox Browser

Comment: No other way. You'd have to give enough error details for us to help

Comment: Did you get any error message when you followed the instructions in the post?

Comment: No I didnt get any errors. It just didnt change anything at all. @RA

Comment: Does your webcam show up if you type `sudo lshw` in a terminal?